# What does "in 6 months" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure about the usage of "in" and "after". For example, it's January now and I got rejected in a job application, some one tells me that I can re-apply in six month. Is this "in" the same as "within"? Does it mean I can re-apply in the period between January and June but not after June? Or does it mean I should re-apply after June?

Comment: *In six months* means *after six months* in this case. After June.

Comment: What is an example that "in" is used as "within"?

Comment: *In the six months I was in office ...*

Comment: Is it true that when "in" is used for the future it always means after that time instant?

Comment: *Future* is not clear in your question. For example *How much can occur **in a year*** is a time reference but is not future, and does not mean *after* but *during*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, *you can re-apply in six months* means you must wait until six months after your first application to file a new one (i.e. June).

If they intended to say that six months was the latest you could re-apply, they would have said *you can re-apply for six months* or *you can re-apply within six months*. You could also communicate this sense by saying *you can re-apply in the next six months*.

Comment: For the form "You can do *something* **in** *some time period*", does it always mean *after*?

Comment: @LoganYang If you say *Call me in an hour*, it means you want me to call you after one hour has passed. If you say *Call me in the **next** hour*, it means you want me to call before one hour has passed.